# mod_rewrite force www prefix selectively working

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, seo

I am utilizing other mod_rewrite conditions in my .htaccess file and also want to ensure that my domain is always prefixed with www (for session storing and seo). However with my current .htaccess if I go to example.com it works great, but if I go to example.com/folder it will redirect to www.example.com (leaving out /folder) Is there something I'm doing wrong here?

my .htaccess file

```
Options +FollowSymLinks  
RewriteEngine on  

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L] 

# Rules for: actions
RewriteRule ^([-_!~*'()$a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$ ./date/index.php?action=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Have you tried removing the action rule to see if that's the problem?

Comment: Try clearing your browsers cache. Could be some old redirect code that is still being cached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rewrite engine is multi-pass.  It loops picking the lowest `.htaccess` file on the path with `RewriteEngine On` until no further rewrite changes occur.  So for this `example.com/folder/xxx` request -- if an `.htaccess` file exists in `DOCROOT/folder` then it will be used and the rewrite rules in `DOCROOT/.htaccess` will be ***ignored***.

You can use a single `.htaccess` in DOCROOT or a hierarchy.  The single DOCROOT `.htaccess` file has a small performance advantage as the engine only needs to open and to read in a single `.htaccess` file.  I describe this in more detail in this article, [More on using Rewrite rules in .htaccess files](http://blog.ellisons.org.uk/article-59)

You are not specifying a `RewriteBase` and so the engine can often lose directories as here in your case. So I would use the following in `DOCROOT/.htaccess`:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks  
RewriteEngine on  
RewriteBase   /
RewriteCond   %{HTTP_HOST}        =example.com
RewriteRule   ^.*                 http://www.example.com/$0   [R=301,L]
```

where DOCROOT is your Apache document root directory.

I am also curious about your inclusion character set for the date pattern.  Seems odd to me, but leaving this aside, it's better written as

```
RewriteRule ^([-_!~*'()$\w]+)/?$  date/index.php?action=$1    [L,QSA]
```

assuming, of course, that you want to activate DOCROOT/date/index.php