# htaccess force www and keep trailing url

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am using the following to redirect my non www. urls to use www.:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://www.domain.com/"
</IfModule>
```

However, if someone visits domain.com/abc-123 it redirects to www.domain.com and loses the remaining of the url.

Any help with this? How can i set it up so it doesn't remove the end of the url?

Miro

Comment: http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/modrewrite-tips-tricks.html#Require_the_www

Comment: http://snipplr.com/view/13398/

Comment: The website has two domains parked on it, so i am trying to avoide having the url hard coded into the htaccess file.

Comment: Look at the second link I posted. It should take care of that also.

Comment: it dosent seem to do it.. let me post the entire htaccess file script.

Comment: Try to comment out everything else and see if it works then. I.e. try to eliminate possible interfering rules first, so that you can more easily isolate the problem. Also use the developer tools of your browser to see what redirections are actually happening (in Chrome for example Tools/Developer Tools/Network).

Comment: Also related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9224462/mod-rewrite-force-www-prefix-selectively-working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just swap the order of the rules around. Since the first (WP) rule is stripping the path, by the time the second rule is applied the path will be empty.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://www.domain.com/"
</IfModule>
```